# Transform the mongoDB data into multiple collections and restore to new server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

##### Problem:

want to replicate mongodb data across servers but also like to alter a few attributes before to restoring.

Server 1 (DB) -> Transform data of collection -> Server 2 (DB)

##### expectation:

Server 1

```
collectionA {
   _id: string
   name: string,
   priceValue: number, 
   orderId: string
}
```

on Server 2 should be

```
collectionA {
   _id: string
   price: number, // alter property name
   orderId: string
}

// create new collection
collectionB {
   _id: string // new ID
   name: string,
   orderId: string
}
```

##### Solution

I found a [npm plugin (mongocopy)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongocopy) that does the same thing, but it is quite slow when dealing with large amounts of data.

Is there any other better solution to migrate the data?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Copy the database as is, then run an aggregation with [$out](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) parameter to extract matching documents to new collection directly on the server without pulling everything to the client.

Comment: @alexBlex still I'm not clear, could you please provide some sudo code for it?

Answer (score 0):

There is not much to explain really. After you export/import the database to new server, login with mongo shell and split the collection to 2:

```
db.collectionA.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: "$name",
      orderId: "$orderId"
    }
  },
  {
    "$out": "collectionB"
  }
]);

db.collectionA.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      price: "$priceValue",
      orderId: "$orderId"
    }
  },
  {
    "$out": "collectionA"
  }
]);
```

`_id: 0` generates new ObjectId, `_id: 1` preserves original value. [Docs for $out parameter](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)